# OpenCV - disable print Exceptions

Tags: c++, opencv, error-handling

I'm quite new in OpenCV, but now I need catch `cv:Exception`. I made try and catch block:

```
try{
    //do some opencv things
}
catch (cv::Exception& e){
    cout << "OpenCV error: " << endl << e.what();
    cin.get();
}
```

It works great, I can catch exception. But exception message is written twice. One from opencv libraries and second from me.

Is there some way to disable send message from opencv to `stderr`? I made release version - change VS2013 to Release and removed "d" from name of all libraries. But it's still written twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [cvRedirectError](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.2_org/c/core_utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#redirecterror) to override OpenCV's default error handling.

You can use it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182235/error-modes-for-opencv?answertab=votes#tab-top):

```
int myErrorHandler(int status, const char* func_name, const char* err_msg, 
                   const char* file_name, int line, void*)
{
    // Do whatever you want here
    return 0;
}

cvRedirectError(myErrorHandler); ///< Call this once somewhere
```

And this is how you would restore the default behavior:

```
cv::redirectError(cv::ErrorCallback())
```